# How to add marker on google map pin

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add a marker to my google maps and for some reason its not showing up. The map itself is working fine, but the marker will not display. I'm following the google api documentation, and all the other customizable features work fine. I have also tried manually adding the Lon and Lat, but nothing. I'm sure its something simple I'm overlooking but I'm not sure what it is, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<% if @location.latitude.present? && @location.longitude.present? %>
    <script>
    function initMap() {

    // Specify features and elements to define styles.
    var styleArray = [
      {
        featureType: "all",
        stylers: [
         { saturation: -80 }
        ]
      },{
        featureType: "road.arterial",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [
          { hue: "#00ffee" },
          { saturation: 50 }
        ]
      },{
        featureType: "poi.business",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [
          { visibility: "off" }
        ]
      }
    ];

    var myLatLng = {lat: <%= @location.latitude %>, lng: <%= @location.longitude %>};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
      // styles: styleArray,
      center: myLatLng
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: <%= @location.name %>
    });
    }

    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?   signed_in=true&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    <div id="map"></div>
   <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems you not have setted the position

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: markerPos,
  map: map,
  title: <%= @location.name %>
});
```

Where is the value for markerPos ..?

```
try with myLatLng


var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  title: <%= @location.name %>
});
```

And just for debugging try without location.name

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map
});
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a variable I forgot to remove from when I was trying to troubleshoot. Its still does not work.

Comment: Thanks for the response scaisEdge, however, I tried that while I was debugging and still nothiing. I'm using a bing API key, not sure if that has something to do with it?

Comment: Seems no because the map is showed .. eventually you can try without key .. (for test)

Comment: There is a warning: Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys, but i figured this was due to using a bing API key.

Comment: Are you sure the map work right .?.. i don't see .. width and height for the map div ... these value must to be setted properly ..

Comment: I suggest you of move the map div  above the js script

Comment: I tried moving the 'map' div above the script but still nothing. The height and width are set in my master.scss, the map works fine.

Comment: I just noticed when I hover over the pin the location displays, similar to how an alt attribute would. If this is how its supposed to work then I apologize, I thought a marker would be fixed to the pin and visible at all times. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: <%= @location.name %>
    });
```

You're outputting the location.name, but that needs to be in a quoted string.  Right now, if you view source and see the client-side code I assume it looks like:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: Hello World
    });
```

You're probably getting a JS error.  Just try:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: '<%= @location.name %>'
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't work either, I tried it out of the box with title: "Hello World"...For some reason its just not showing up.

Comment: Sounds like you're confusing markers with infowindows.  As you discovered the 'title' property simply shows up when you hover over the marker.